# Call back function and Promise function not working perfect - Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am triggering the `child_added` event, which listens when a new child is added to a node (parent).Inside it, is another event, `value` . To load the data from firebase it takes, milliseconds, and in that time, the next line is executed before the data is retrieved. I have used the promise with then() and even tried callbacks, but  both did not work for me. is there anything considered to be wrong with my code. What I want is, when the data is fully loaded, then the `pupoluateUsers()` function should be called. Other wise wait until it.

[The promise method I have tried](https://jsfiddle.net/L886ed3t/)

[The callback method I have tried](https://jsfiddle.net/am4f9p0f/)

The Sample code, I am working with now :

```js
$("body").on("click",".si-add",function(e){

      var _CU = $.cookie("_cu"),
          _MT = $(this).parent().attr("data-id"),
          _chattedWith = [],
          _child_key = [];

      _firebaseChatRef.child(_CU).child(_MT).set(true).then(function(){});

       _firebaseChatRef.child(_CU).on("child_added",function(res){
     
         _firebaseAuthRef.child(res.key).on("value",function(r){
            
            populateUsers({name:r.val().n,id:r.key});
            
        })

      })
          

      function populateUsers(chattedWith){
      

        let len = chattedWith.length,
            _el = document.getElementsByClassName("chat-ind-body-wrap")[0];
          


          
          _el.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin','<li class="chat-ind-user active-user" data-id="'+chattedWith.id+'">'
                                              +'<div class="chat-ind-user-img">'
                                                +'<img src="assets/1.jpg">'
                                              +'</div>'
                                              +'<div class="chat-ind-user-data">'
                                                +'<div class="ciu-name"> '+chattedWith.name+' </div>'
                                                +'<div class="ciu-text"> Hi, I am the text here ! </div>'
                                                +'<span class="ciu-time"> 2h ago </span>'
                                              +'</div>'
                                              +'<span class="user-availble">'
                                                +'<i class="fa fa-circle"></i>'
                                              +'</span>'
                                            +'</li>');
        
      }



});
```

Comment: there are no images @trincot

Comment: No they are the JSfiddle links, not images

Comment: I am very sorry I misinterpreted that. I take back my comments!

Comment: Its ok mate :).